# Deleting buffers when exiting

Tags: c++, linux, buffer, freebsd

I understand that it is good practice to delete buffers in your code if you no longer need them in order to free up memory. What happens if you don't and your program finishes execution? Does the buffer remain in memory occupying space until you power off? or does the system automatically clear it through garbage collection?

learning C++ on my own so please excuse my noobishness

Comment: If you have a real OS like Linux or FreeBSD, it reclaims resources when your process exits.

Comment: However, it's good to reclaim them yourself, at least in debug mode, because letting the OS clean up variables that exist until process exit makes it more difficult to use memory profiling tools (like `valgrind`) to find leaks that should have been reclaimed earlier.

Comment: It seems inconceivable that this hasn't been asked before, but I can't find a duplicate. Probably not searching with the right keywords. Anyway, seconding what @BenVoigt says.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks! that makes a lot of sense. And yeah it appears I was searching it with the wrong keywords

Answer (score 1):

Every non-toy operating system will track all memory allocated to a process, and reclaim all of that when the process exits.